# Subquery returns more than 1 row, Error 1242

Tags: mysql, sql

I am very new to MySQL, can you guys please help me in this?

Query:

```
UPDATE users u,
       posts p
SET    u.tags = (SELECT group_concat(Tags)
                 FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Tags,
                                         user_id
                         FROM   posts
                         GROUP  BY tags,
                                   user_id) AS p
                 GROUP  BY user_id)
WHERE  u.user_id = p.user_id;
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: It looks like your subquery returns more than one row, while it's expecting just one. Try running the subquery alone and see if the results are what you expected.

Comment: Inner query returning multiple records based on user_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery:

```
update users u
   set u.tags =(select group_concat(Distinct Tags)
                from posts p
                where p.user_id = u.user_id
                group by user_id )
```

I'm not sure what your query is doing.  It has a join on the outside that is unnecessary.  It is grouping by tags and user_id on the inside, with an unnecessary `distinct` keyword.  The subquery is producing a different value for `each user_id`, so it is no wonder that you are getting an error of too many rows returned.  A `set` statement can only have one value.